# Getting Parameter value in java with symbol Apostrophe(') query

Tags: java, mysql

I have parameter named paramValue then I am trying to store it this is working if my paramvalue is equals to any value without apostrophe like paramvalue = 'klang@'
but if it has apostrophe it wont work like this paramvalue = 'kl'ang@'
I put some part of my code

```
query += "'" + paramValue + "'";
```

I tried this but I am getting error like '; expected' Is there any other option to do it like this below I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
query += """ + paramValue + """;
```

below is my code

```
public boolean insertInto(String tableName, String paramsName[], String paramsValues[], String id) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO tbl1" + tableName + " (id, dateCreated, dateModified";
        for (String paramName : paramsName) {
            query += ", c_" + paramName;
        }
        query += ") VALUES( ";
        if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
            query += "UUID(), NOW() , NOW()";
        } else {
            query += "'" + id + "', NOW(), NOW()";
        }
        for (String paramValue : paramsValues) {
            query += "'" + paramValue + "'";
        }
        query += ")";

        Connection con = null;
        //myconn
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            return stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would abandon the aim of trying to quote the value yourself. Use parameterized SQL instead with PreparedStatement. Then you can specify the value in the parameter, and keep the data entirely separate from the SQL. This avoids SQL injection attacks as well as data conversion issues, and also improves the code readability IMO.

Comment: To add to Jon's comment: doing it like you're trying to will make your code vulnerable to SQL injection. If you use `PreparedStatement` instead it will be less of a problem as the parameters will get properly escaped. Additional benefit: this will make [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) happy ;)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I really appreciate all of your suggestion I am using  PreparedStatement stmt it just I am not sure how to make it work yeah to aim of trying to quote the value I am sorry I am still beginner I am trying to learn thank you all

Comment: You are not passing parameters to your prepared statement, thus defeating its purpose.  I posted a link to a tutorial. Start there.

Comment: I replace all the single quote to double quote worked really appreciate all of your suggestion thank you